# How to capture loss of RC signal with DJI Onboard SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I've gone through all the documents and cannot find out how to capture the RC loss of signal and allow the on-board embedded system (OES) to control the DJI M100 UAV through the OSDK commands.

Any ideas on how to allow OES to control the DJI M100 when there's a loss of RC signal.  Currently the flight controller forces a return to home, or hover, or land, but not allowing the on-board embedded system to control the UAV.

Answer (score 0):

In some of the mission structs, there is an RCLostAction unsigned integer member that lets you specify the action to take on RC communication lost. For example, in the Upload Waypoint Mission Settings section from the [Ground Station Protocol](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/introduction/ground-station-protocol.html) page:

```
uint8_t RCLostAction;   //Action on rc lost                   
                        //0: exit waypoint and failsafe
                        //1: continue the waypoint
```

You can set RCLostAction to 1, which should have the aircraft continue the mission.

I hope this helps.